# Getting the file's name regardless of the arguments position in CLI in golang

Tags: unix, go, terminal, command-line-arguments

Hello I've been trying to make my own pastebin script to get used to golang,As I was making it, I came across an issue after I tried to get rid of the -f flag that holds the file's name
I tried to make it like any regular UNIX command, example
`ls -la file` works the same as `ls file -la`.

I've reading about flag package in golang, but didn't seem to find anything that can help me fix such a problem. This is my first post here, I searched for similar questions but didn't find any. Thank you

Comment: Having flags after non-flag arguments is generally considered a bad/confusing idea, even if lots of tools from the 1970s do it; the `flag` package *does* help (with its `Args` function) as long as you're willing to keep your non-flag arguments (i.e. the filename) at the end.

Comment: Oh! I seem to missed that one, thank you for the help.

Comment: If you really want to achieve this then the option is to parse each of the args and determine if the arg is a flag or file, regex and os.Path() should help.